# Java Hashtable class - Does this thing work the way I think it does? Specific questions included

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a class called Node that I've written. I overrode the hashCode() function of it to take into account two fields of the Node (there is also a third field which doesn't affect the my hashCode() function). I also wrote an equals() function which takes all three fields into account.

I'm trying to use the Hashtable class to store Nodes so that I can easily check later on when I make new nodes whether the new nodes are duplicates of ones in the hashtable or not. So far I have this

```
 Hashtable<Node,Node> hashTbl = new Hashtable<Node,Node>();
 ...
 Node node1 = // some new node
 hashTbl.put(node1,node1);
 ...
```

So now, say I make a new node called node2 which has the exact same hash value as node1, but is not equal to node1 as defined by the equals() method. I want to check whether node2 is a duplicate of anything in the hash table (it's not), but if I use constainsKey(), won't that give me a false positive? It seems like using containsValue() wouldn't be utilizing the efficiency of the hash table. So how can I do this efficiently?

Also, my assumption is that when I call hashTbl.put(arg1,arg2), it calls the hashCode() function of arg1 and uses that value to find an index in an "array" to place arg2 in. Is this right?

Sorry for being kind of confusing. Thanks anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you probably want a HashSet (or something similar), not a Hashtable - all you are trying to do is check for membership, and a HashSet will allow you to do that without needing to provide a value for every key.

To answer your question, the determines which slot in the array that the value gets put in, but every slot is actually a linked list.  If the new key is not `.equal` to any other key in the linked list, the new key and value are put in their own node in the linked list.  Simply returning 1 for all objects is a perfectly legal and correct `.hashcode` implementation.  The only issue with that implementation is that it turns Hashtables and similar data structures into linked lists (which obviously causes you to lose all the performance benefits of the Hashtable).

In short, your `.hashcode` method will work fine.  If you put a large number of objects that aren't `.equal` but have the same hashcode, performance will decrease, but the code will still function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially right: the hashtable (btw, [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is the newer, more recommended class) uses `hashCode()` to find a bucket to put your object in. If there's a collision (another object in the same bucket), it uses a list within each bucket, using `equals(Object)` to find out if this new object is already equal to one of the objects in the hash (or, in a lookup, to see whether the lookup key matches one of the key-value pairs). So in the worst case of all collisions, your hash turns into a list with O(N) operations. As you point out, this is inefficient.

As long as your `equals(Object)` is correct, there won't be a functional problem -- just an efficiency issue if your hashCode produces too many conflicts. Basically, if two objects are equal, they must have the same hashCode for correctness; if two objects are not equal, they should have different hashCodes for hashing efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

A HashTable (or HashMap) contains N bins, where a bin can hold more than one Object.  (Each bin is effectively a linked list of Map.Entry).  The hashCode() of the key is used to determine the bin.  However, after determining the bin, equals() is then used on the key to see if the key is already there.  So, if you put node1 and node2 into the HashTable, and both have the same hashCode() but are not equal, they will go into the same bin, but that bin will be a linked list of length two, with two keys, node1 and node2, and corresponding values.

containsKey() will NOT give you a false positive, as it will use the hashCode() to find the bin, but then will do an equals on all the keys for that bin.  Having the same hashCode for a bunch of keys makes the HashTable slow and inefficient (if all the values have the same hashCode, in effect, you are storing in a linked list) but will not break the contract.